# AVURLAsset cannot load with remote file

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I have a problem using AVURLAsset.

```
NSString * const kContentURL = @

"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8";
...

    NSURL *contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kContentURL];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:contentURL
                                               options:nil];
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tracksKey]
                            completionHandler:^{
    ...
                               NSError *error = nil;
                               AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:tracksKey
                                                                              error:&error];
    ...
    }
```

In the completion block, the status is AVKeyValueStatusFailed and the error message is "Cannot Open". All exemples I have seen, use a local file, so maybe there is a problem using a remote file...

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't directly create an `AVURLAsset` for an HTTP Live stream as stated in Apple's [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW3).
You'll have to create an `AVPlayerItem` with the stream url and instantiate an AVPlayer with it

```
AVPlayerItem *pItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:theStreamURL];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:pItem];
```

If you need to have access to the `AVURLAsset` behind that you could follow these steps.

Step 1/ register for changes of the `status` property of the player item

```
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

Step 2/ in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context { 
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        AVPlayerItem *pItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
        if (pItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
            // Here you can access to the player item's asset
            // e.g.: self.asset = (AVURLAsset *)pItem.asset;
        }
    }   
}
```

**EDIT**: corrected the answer

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution but observer method on currentItem value is not called because property is already set when I add the observer. So I placed an observer method on status of AVPlayerItem, and from here I was able to get AVPlayer currentItem.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, thanks! Mixed up with another part of my code... I've edited my answer to correct that.