# Using the AVURLAsset to play a Remote Video File

Tags: ios, video, avurlasset

I want to use the AVURLAsset to play a video file but on a server not local file. I have read that the AVURLAsset cant be used directly for remote files .
I read another link of stack Overflow

[AVURLAsset cannot load with remote file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934886/avurlasset-cannot-load-with-remote-file)

this link has some method to use AVURLAsset to play remote files but I am not able to understand it fully. My observer is not being called. Can someone please help me? Actually I don't want to use AVPlayer to play video for some reasons. I am grabbing frames from AVAsset and then rendering them as textures in OpenGL so I need to do this by AVURLAsset only.

Here is code to look at

```
-(void) startPlayer
   { 
    NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://gamooz.com/wildlife.mp4"]; 
    pItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url]; 
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:pItem];
    [player play]; 
    pItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil]; 
   }

 -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:    (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
   { 
     NSLog(@"heyy"); 
     if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
        {
          AVPlayerItem *pItemTemp = (AVPlayerItem *)object; 
          if (pItemTemp.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) 
             { 
                ///now i can use playerItem asset
                 asset = (AVURLAsset *)pItemTemp.asset; 
             }
        } 
   }
```

but the observer is never getting called. Why is that?

Also I put the observer code in some other function and tried to check if the playerItem is ready to play

```
 -(void) checkForPlayer
   {
  if (pItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) 
   {
     asset = (AVURLAsset *)pItem.asset;
   }
   }
```

it is never giving status equal to ready.

Comment: Can you provide some code to look at?

Comment: @adamjansch
-(void) startPlayer{
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://link"];
 pItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
 player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:pItem];
 [player play];
 [pItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {  if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        AVPlayerItem *pItemTemp = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
        if(pItemTemp.status==AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
asset = (AVURLAsset *)pItemTemp.asset;
}}}

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? Use the edit link underneath the tags.